# I want to save email details in database with REST API call

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createXXX", method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> createXXX(@Context HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpSession, 
            @Valid @RequestParam("json") String jsonString,@Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile[] files)  {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AModel aModel = null;
        try {
            aModel = mapper.readValue(jsonString, AModel.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

Someone else is using the REST API published by us and content type is multipart/form-data, consumers of API will send a JSON string and some file attachments, JSON string is like

```
{
    "mail":"xxx.com",
    "mailSubject":"Hi how are you",
    "mailBody":"here we can have anything rich text, html etc which we are generally writing while sending the mails"
}
```

I am facing problem to consume this mailBody because this will be rarely is a normal string, so JSON parser is giving an error.

```
error: {
    "errorCode": 400,
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "ERR-0001: Required parameters are blank or invalid.",
    "timestamp": "29-08-2018 07:06:17",
    "Errors": [
        {
            "field": "",
            "rejectedValue": "json",
            "message": "Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@74be551a; line: I, column: 134]"
        }
    ]
}
```

so i want to change the API structure so that we can consume the mail body inside the json string or outside the json string.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like your controller codes?

Comment: If your API specifies that it requires a JSON object, then the consumer must provide a valid JSON object. If they don't, your API is correct in returning a 400.